# How to Access cell imageView from didSelectRowAtindexPath: function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im trying to use core animation for an `UIImageView` in a cell. Im not sure how to access the cell or the `UIImageView`.

Im using swift 5.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CountryListCell
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        let str =  factsJsonList[indexPath.row].country
        let image =  UIImage(named: str)


        cell.flagImageView.image = image
        cell.flagNameLabel.text = str.uppercased()

        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let cell = [tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)]
        // TODO :core animate the image view

        let vc = CountryFactListVC()
        vc.country = factsJsonList[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: do you want to access image in didselect method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//access the current cell

     guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CountryListCell 
     else{
       return 
     }
        // TODO :core animate the image view

        let imageViewToAnimate = cell.flagImageView //you can use this object to animate image view of cell


     }
```

Comment: Don't do this. Access the data from your data model, not from the cell.

Comment: @maddy, how can you access imageview from datamodel? Its an UI element.

Comment: I may have misread the need here. My comment was based on needing access to the image, not the image view.

Comment: Okay.... No problem, i just wanted to know if there may be some other way to access this..

Answer (score 0):

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//access the current cell

         guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CountryListCell else{
    return 
    }
            // TODO :core animate the image view

            let vc = CountryFactListVC()
            vc.country = factsJsonList[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
```